# DefaultCellEditor and its component's JFormattedTextField properties are not applied on the first click, but only at the second one

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield

I have a code that runs the `DefaultCellEditor` on the `JTable`'s cell single click. I expect, that at the same first click the cell will have null border, `MaskFormatter` will format the field and field will have some value set to it and having caret at the beginning (leftmost).

```
  JFormattedTextField priceField = new JFormattedTextField();
    try {
      priceField.setFormatterFactory(new DefaultFormatterFactory(new MaskFormatter("#.####")));
      priceField.setValue("0.0000");
      priceField.setBorder(null);
      priceField.setCaretPosition(0);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    TableColumn priceColumn = changeTrafficProviderTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(4);
    DefaultCellEditor priceCellEditor = new DefaultCellEditor(priceField);
    priceCellEditor.setClickCountToStart(0);
    priceColumn.setCellEditor(priceCellEditor);

    JFormattedTextField prefixField = new JFormattedTextField();
    try {
      prefixField.setFormatterFactory(new DefaultFormatterFactory(new MaskFormatter("##")));
      prefixField.setBorder(null);
      prefixField.setValue("00");
      prefixField.setCaretPosition(0);
      
    } catch (ParseException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    TableColumn prefixColumn = changeTrafficProviderTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(3);
    DefaultCellEditor prefixCellEditor = new DefaultCellEditor(prefixField);
    prefixCellEditor.setClickCountToStart(0);
    prefixColumn.setCellEditor(prefixCellEditor);
```

In fact, I have only null border and MaskFormatter applied at the first click. The value set and caret put to the beginning (left) is done on the second click.

I can't find any event associated with the first click and the second click to debug the different behavior. Please give some ideas how to fix that.

1. The first click, I have caret blinking. It is at the end and the text isn't set

[image]

[image]

2. Do some click ountsine on another field:

[image]

3. Click to Price column again. The text is set, and the caret is placed according to the code

[image]

So, why the neighbor lines of code are applied at two moments?